# AWS Appsync schema error (Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete)

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Working on a React app with AWS Appsync and trying graphQL for the first time. My `schema.graphql` makes sense to me but throwing an error that I don't really know how to see what's going on.

It's an app where users can make a post and comment with a notification system. Getting `Resource is not in the state stackUpdateComplete` error message on `amplify push`

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  following: [User]
  follower: [User]
  post: [Post] @connection(name: "UserPost")
  comment: [Comment] @connection(name: "UserComment")
  notification: [Notification] @connection(name: "UserNotification")
}

type Post @model {
  id: ID!
  user: User! @connection(name: "UserPost")
  privacy: String!
  content: String!
  loved: [User]
  comment: [Comment] @connection(name: "PostComment")
}

type Comment @model {
  id: ID!
  user: User! @connection(name: "UserComment")
  content: String!
  loved: [User]
  post: Post @connection(name: "PostComment")
}

type Notification @model {
  id: ID!
  content: String!
  link: String!
  category: String!
  user: User! @connection(name: "UserNotification")
}
```

Can anyone see anything wrong on my schema file and know how to debug the error in the best way on Appsync?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual error message you are seeing.

Comment: @DanielReardenThank you for the comment. I just added an error message.

Comment: Q: Is it a problem to delete the whole stack and then build it again? Maybe also check CloudFormation for any error. Check also Cognito in the CLI because of the reference to the "User".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is known to happen when there are changes to `connection` directives wich triggers updates DynamoDB GSI. Cloudformation has  update limits for DynamoDB GSIs. Amplify team is actively working on `@key` directive which will replace the `@connection` directive. In the time being follow these steps if you're making changes to `@connection` directive

1. Make only one change in `@connection` directive per push. If you want to rename a connection, first remove the connection and do a push and then add it with the new name
2. If a push results in failure and subsequent pushes may result in `Resolver not found`. This is caused by the Cloudformation implementation where a rollback removed the resolvers but did not create the original resolver. You could overcome this issue by adding missing resolvers in AppSync console.

Ref: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1406#issuecomment-494533788